# Dojo Mobile ScreenSizeAware not working in Worklight 6?

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am interesting in experimenting with ScreenSizeAware as a way to keep from having to write separate apps for cellphones versus tablets. Was this feature not included in the Dojo code supplied with Worklight 6?

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware.html#dojox-mobile-screensizeaware

"All you need to do is to require dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware and place the following tag somewhere in your application."

`<span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware"></span>`

I started up a fresh Worklight app in Eclipse and made sure I am requiring dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware and dojox/mobile/FixedSplitter. I put the span statement in an otherwise empty UI and ran it in the browser simulator, Firebug immediately shows a JavaScript error occurring in default/layers/mobile-ui-layer.js; Splitter not found.

I tried requiring dojox/mobile/Splitter but there isn't any such thing. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You add other code.See [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware.html#id5) example

Comment: Yes I was working directly from that example as you can see from the link I provided above. I cut and pasted the example code straight into my app including the device theme, the style, and the requires. "Splitter not found". Have you tried it in Worklight 6?

Comment: Worklight 6 moved to Dojo 1.9, and uses a different directory structure. My concern is that the screen-aware feature may not have been included.